# Хочу создать текстового помощника но не знаю с чего начать

Tags: python

Хочу создать текстового помощника но не знаю с чего начать
Будет здорово если Вы посоветуйте интересные статьи или репозиторий с github на эту тему
Возможно у Вас есть готовый код ( буду благодарен если Вы им поделитесь  )

Требования
*Основной язык должен быть Python
*Язык русский / английский
*Должен потреблять не больше 4Gb ОЗУ
*Быть многопоточным (Не обязательно)

P.S В программи́ровании Я мало что понимаю (недавно начал) но главное ведь желание )

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Начните с ответа на свой вопрос... текстовый помощник - это что?
Что бы сделать это правильно, разбейте вопрос на 3 части:

1. Что "помощник" должен выдать.
2. Что "помощник" должен получить, что бы выдать нужное.
3. Подумайте какими способами из пункта 2 дойти в пункт 1.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил слово "Как" в первые 2 пункта - "Что и как", но боюсь это будет совсем сложно =). Исходя из "многопоточным", однако.

Comment: Каждый пункт можно и нужно делить на 3 аналогично. Пока реализация не станет более мене понятной. Тогда можно и кодить... )

Comment: Что то сделал но все не то  (
https://github.com/DonteBoy/assistant-/blob/main/cod

Comment: Очередная "качелька из покрышки и веревок в дереве" )) Хорошо хоть текстовый, а то если GUI пришлось бы сначала окошко рисовать? Да?

Comment: И не говори 
«Лень двигатель прогресса» а Я очень прогрессивный  )

Comment: «Лень двигатель прогресса» - ложь. Двигатель прогресса - разница между ценой и себестоимостью.